# How to prevent unwanted get parameter in canonical tags

Tags: typo3, canonical-link

Canonical tags are used better search but Google sometimes adds unwanted parameters to the URL with cHash. Have read so many posts, everyone express it as a bug but couldn't find any answer. Have anyone have solution

Required:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://myexample.com">
```

Actual:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://myexample.com?bla=blup&amp;cHash=e7fe4c19f1fd9ee41e36390f9bc2bfe2">
```

Excludeparameters is not a solution for me, as my parameter list is expected grow huge.

Comment: As you describe it, the "unwanted parameters" are added by TYPO3, not by Google. - If I am right, the question is which extension is responsable for the parameters. If you know the extension you have to add specific rules in your sites configuration to transform the "unwanted parameters" into a speaking URL. Please check documentation on sites configuration with extensions.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply. The extenstion is EXT:seo. Can please explain me more what site configurations are you referring to.

Answer (score 0):

It's **not** a bug. TYPO3 needs the cHash to identify different variants of a certain page, which differs caused by the other params.

Expecting `http://myexample.com` is showing *other* content than `http://myexample.com?bla=blup&amp;cHash=e7fe4c19f1fd9ee41e36390f9bc2bfe2`, the canonical have to differ.

If they are showing the *same content* and the additional parameters are only for tracking or things like that (like `pk_campaign,pk_kwd,utm_source,utm_medium,utm_campaign`), then `[FE][cacheHash][excludedParameters]` is your friend: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/Configuration/Typo3ConfVars/FE.html#excludedparameters

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as I mentioned in the question my parameter list is expected to grow and I have tried [excludedParameters], its not the solution for me.

Comment: I explained the technical background. If that does not meet your criteria and the suggested solution is "not the solution for you", maybe TYPO3 is the wrong tool for you use-case 